# Java equivalent to .NET System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: java, exception

I am not as familiar with Java's exception packages as with those of .NET. I'm in a situation where, if programming in C#, I would throw a `System.InvalidOperationException`.

Before creating my own `java.lang.RuntimeException` subclass, I need to know if there is a similar exception type I should throw in Java.

The exact scenario is:

My class is a value object that provides an `int intValue()` method, returning an int. However, in some situations, the current value cannot be provided as an int, so this class also provides a `boolean isInteger()` to allow API users to know when `intValue()` can be safely invoked.

If a caller calls `intValue()` when `isInteger()` is `false`, an exception should be thrown.

And the question is: What type of exception?

I know that this question might not have a *correct* answer, but considering that I don't have lots of experience designing Java APIs, I want to know from other Java developers what they would expect to be thrown in this scenario.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Java equivalent of C#'s InvalidOperationException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165701/is-there-a-java-equivalent-of-cs-invalidoperationexception)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Throw an [`IllegalStateException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html):

> Signals that a method has been invoked
>   at an illegal or inappropriate time.
>   In other words, the Java environment
>   or Java application is not in an
>   appropriate state for the requested
>   operation.

Comment: `IllegalStateException` is definitely correct for the specific case that was asked about.  Note that in some situations I believe it may be more appropriate to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.  For example if an `Iterator` does not support the `remove` method.